# How to use bundle.js to build react project in eclipse over tomcat

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, reactjs, bundle

I'm creating a Dynamic web project that consuming REST service with reactjs frontend. The project structure is as follows:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyrO3.png)

The rest service is as follows:

```
package webService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter;
import org.voltdb.VoltTable;
//import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
//import java.util.Date;
import org.voltdb.client.*;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import x.dp.*;

@Path("/WebService")
public class RestService {

@GET
@Path("/getdata")
@Produces("application/json")

public Response feed()
{

        VoltDAOImpl voltDao = new VoltDAOImpl();
        Map<String ,List<HashMap<String,String>>> returnList=       voltDao.getOrderDetails("PEAKM" , "Hydra" ,
                 "" ,  voltDao.client,"notional" ,1000);
        List<HashMap<String,String>> orderDetailsList=      returnList.get("order_details");
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

            String json = null;
            try {
                json = ow.writeValueAsString(orderDetailsList);
                System.out.println(json);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





    return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
}}
```

I'm consuming it in the RefData.js file like this:

```
function findByName()
{
    console.log("inside");
    var returnval;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(json){  

            returnval = json;

        }

    });
    return returnval;
}
```

Later this RefData.js is used in myApp.jsx (not important from question perspective though):

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import RefData from './RefData';
import RowDataFactory from './RowDataFactory';
import ColDefFactory from './ColDefFactory.jsx';
import './myApp.css';
import 'ag-grid-root/dist/styles/theme-blue.css';

// take this line out if you do not want to use ag-Grid-Enterprise
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
....
...
.....
```

my index.html is as follows:

```
<html style="height: 100%;">

    <!-- This index file is common for both the standard and large examples. As to which project you are running
        depends on whether you use 'npm run standard' or 'npm run large' -->

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" >
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
        <!-- Example uses font awesome icons -->
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <!-- Put some spacing around the buttons - not needed, just makes it look nice -->
    <style>
        button {
            margin-left: 4px;
            margin-right: 4px;
        }
    </style>

    <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto">     
        <div id="myAppContainer" style="height: 73%;"></div>
    </div></div></body></html>
```

How do I run this react project using tomcat? Because earlier I was using npm to run it with static data sample and it ran fine, but now I want to use tomcat? How do I build with bundle.js?

Comment: My guess is your build process will be at least two fold: 1) You build your `bundle.js` file (and any other static resources) with your `webpack` command, then you 2) Create a WAR file for Tomcat, which includes a) your compiled server side code, and b) the static resources from 1).

Comment: @lux So, do I remove <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script> from index.html?

Comment: Nope, your page still needs to know where your javascript is, just make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @lux It's giving me Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for some js files. Where do I add my webpack.config.js in my RestServiceProject folder or in the WebContent folder?